# Shifting image behind perlin noise flow field doesn't work in Atom

Tags: perlin-noise

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. I made a Perlin Noise flow field in Atom. Behind that flow field I set an image and that worked fine. But when I want to make that image shift a bit to the right after x seconds (and back), I don't get it to work. The flow field is now behind the image instead of the other way around.
I get that the flow field starts in the setup and thats the reason why I can't set my image in the draw, but does someone know a solution?
You can see my code on: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/423718

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This is probably mistagged, as it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Atom, the XML format.

Comment: Whoops, edited the tag, thanks!

Comment: Your link didn't seem to do anything at all. I tried three different browsers on Win7, 64 & got nothing. I was able to view sketches featured on the openprocessing.org homepage, though.